# ng-file-upload getting TypeError: Illegal invocation with ngf-drop

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

The `TypeError: Illegal invocation` occurs when adding a `$watch` with `objectEquality` set to true on a model which contains a file(s) property used by `ngf-drop`.

Also as reported [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/776).

How can I `$watch` the model without getting this error?

Comment: maybe it's the prob about deep-watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034831/ng-file-upload-getting-typeerror-illegal-invocation-with-ngf-drop/34574471#34574471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved without having to use a separate scope variable for the files.

Instead of `$watch`ing the model, I `$watch`ed a function that returns `Json.stringify(model)` -- with `objectEquality` `true`.

It works, and does not seem to harm perfomance in a user-visible manner.

Answer (score 5):

I have to say, don't ever try deep watching a complex object, which means:

```
$scope.$watch('aComplexObject', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // ...
}, true); // <<< this 'true' may cause the error.
```